# Is it common for employee to ask for condolence letter from the company?

Tags: professionalism, death

My grandpa passed away yesterday, and my parents thought that it would be a good idea to get a condolence letter from my company, something like [here](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2005/10/more_on_writing.html). My parents were born and raised in Asian country, while I'm currently working in US. I have personally never heard of the case where a company writes such letter to a deceased relative of an employee, but it sounds like it's a norm in my parents' country.

I have talked to HR about the request, and they were bewildered, telling me that they have never heard of such letter. They suggested that I talk to the legal department if the company can actually write the condolence letter. I thought that it is an overkill to contact the legal department for somewhat simple letter. Is such request abnormal/rare in US workplace? Googling business condolence letter produced many results, so I'm assuming that it is not entirely unheard of.

If it is relevant, my company is large, with more than 1000+ employees.

Comment: They feel it will be a good idea why?

Comment: While it's certainly not uncommon for a company (or perhaps a group of employees in the company) to offer condolences (usually in the form of a 'greeting' card) - asking for one seems just plain weird (from my European/USA/Western context) ...

Comment: I feel like you should be getting more clarification from your parents.  It's reasonable to ask HR if they do provide this but questionable asking them to provide it if it's not a normal function they perform.

Comment: This is not part of my answer but rather curiosity about the culture that *does* it: doesn't *asking* for condolences kinda defeat the purpose of it?

Comment: Condolences to you personally on your bereavement are normal enough. But not many companies (none I know of) would track all your relatives to even know they passed away, let alone write a condolence letter to your parents rather than you. 1000 employees would mean tracking 10's of thousands of relatives I would think.

Comment: You could just write the letter yourself, explain the cultural significance to your boss or HR, and ask them to sign it.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the point of the letter? What purpose does it serve? Are you traveling to their home country for funeral proceedings and need the letter to swing a cheaper fare on a flight? We need some more context on this one.

Answer (score 20):

> Is such request abnormal/rare in US workplace?

Ah, yes. If they did not know your relatives, the larger the company, the less it will care. Expect verbal condolences from co-workers and team leaders, maybe even bosses higher up the chain if you know them and meet them in person, but there is no part of HR writing condolences in large corporations.

What some western companies do is offer a paid-day-off in case a very close relative dies, so you can attend the funeral without having to worry about your paycheck. But even that comes as a box to tick on your "day off" form without special letters from HR.

Answer (score 8):

I'm so sorry for your loss!

> Is such request abnormal/rare in US workplace?

It used to be relatively common that HR, upon being notified of a death in an employee's family, would send off a quick letter of condolence on behalf of the company.

I received one myself when my grandfather passed away many, many years ago.

But that seems rather rare in these less formal workplace days. In fact letters on the whole have often been replaced by emails. When a sad or happy occasion occurs for an employee these days, an email is typically sent out, sometimes followed up by a card that has been passed around for signatures. I haven't seen letters being sent in a long time.

> I have talked to HR about the request, and they were bewildered,
>   telling me that they have never heard of such letter. They suggested
>   that I talk to the legal department if the company can actually write
>   the condolence letter.

That's just laziness and ignorance on the part of HR. They could easily have performed the same Google search that you did. There's no excuse for them to pass off your request to Legal. Shame on them!

Comment: Condolences to a bereaved employee is not the same as condolences addressed to a deceased relative of the employee - the first is still quite common, the second is something I haven't heard of before.

Comment: I think the important point here is that a condolence letter is simply a nice gesture, not something that you'd ever need, and it's not something that you'd request (in the US, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for your loss.

You have not specified the Asian country, but here in India (which is also an Asian country, by the way), it is common for employers to have, or at least, pretend to have, a personal connect with their employees. An employer sending condolence messages on the death of a close family member (grandparents certainly qualify) is not unusual, but *not* sending such a letter is also not a social "crime".

An employee *asking* for such a letter does sound strange here as well. However, I am also deeply disappointed to hear how your HR handled the request. They could have just given you the letter and be done with it. It does say something about how much they care for their employees if they cannot even write condolences without taking approval from Legal. As Joe says in his answer, shame on them!

Comment: If they have no idea what to write and if they are getting in any trouble for it, of course they cannot just do it and be done with it. If I get a request of something I cannot judge the consequences of, I am better off refusing and redirecting the person to someone who for me seems better suited to judge said consequences.

Comment: HR professionals have no idea what to write in a condolence letter and they could get in trouble for it? Then that entire setup sounds messed up to me. I guess some people just like to look for ways to make life more complicated. In any case, they could have contacted legal themselves instead of putting the employee in a fix.

Comment: @skymningen Professionals people would be interested to know the answer instead of delegate it.

Answer (score 1):

Some companies will do it and others don't.  Heck one place I worked sent a huge flower arrangement and a letter.

The bottom line is *its up the to the Employer* and the policies they have in place, and I don't think I would ever ask for one.

Just inform them of your loss, and leave it at that. ( in the future )  I would not bring it up again if I were you. ( to your current employer )

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal in the US to write a condolence letter?

It's not part of official practice.  There's no legal/tax/career implication to employees having one (or not having one), it's a social nicety and that's about it.  For that reason, you won't find a standard part of the company who know it's responsible for getting out condolence letters. Groups like HR get way more focused on W4's, proof of employment, citizenship processes, and healthcare as they are much more tied into the company's obligations as a business in the US.

> What's the benefit?

The benefit, at least in the US, to having such a letter is only that you have evidence of working for a classy company that shows that it cares.  The letter doesn't get you anything (benefits, future employment, etc).  So the lack of it doesn't hurt you in any way.

For that reason, most people won't ask for one - the reassurance of having *coworkers* who care is displayed in all sorts of different ways, and that's what matters most to most people.  I suspect that this IS quite different from Asian countries, where the relationship between the official company and the individual is quite different and it might be much more important for the company to recognize a personal loss.

> What generally happens?

Different companies and different bosses treat this differently.  Any decent boss will find a way to recognize your loss and try to give you support and reassurance in this sad time.  But most bosses will choose their own way.

In older style companies, it's not uncommon for your boss, the company, and/or your work group to buy flowers and write a nice note that is delivered at a wake or the funeral.  It's easy enough to set this up with florists and funereal homes, and often it's easier to say with flowers what's so hard to say with words.  It creates a very visual display of the company's support of you in your time of loss.

But all of that is rather American-centric - it rather assumes that:

- you'll have a typical Christian style wake and funereal
- you have your death rites in the US
- you aren't allergic to flowers!
- such a public display would feel appropriate to you and your family

I suspect that many offices these days realize on some level that this approach may not feel right - either for the givers or the receivers.  Also, the general increasing casualness and removing of typical social niceties means that less old-school offices/bosses may shy away from such a formal recognition.  Instead I'd expect, still, a boss to write you a note, send you an email, or at least say something caring and consoling and check in with you more often to make sure you're doing OK.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I have never heard of or seen such a condolence. I lost my childhood custodial guardian 2 years ago, and my manager and department co-workers certainly offered their condolences, but the company? No.

Now, to the question: as I see it, it's not your place to ask your employer to do anything (especially a non-trivial thing) when it pertains to your personal life. I try to keep them separate as much as possible. This is, to me, like asking them to attend the funeral. A boss said a while back that he was asked to come to the funeral of a co-worker's husband. He barely knew the employee and had met the husband only once. It made him extremely uncomfortable and he was asking our team what he should do, as he was very unsure what the American custom was.

I was thrown off. Never would I have dreamed this could happen. I was invited to a co-worker's wedding once, but we all worked closely together. I wouldn't have gone to her sister's wedding, surely.

It's an odd idea to me, as a native of the States.